# React Function loading initial value for Radio Group and selecting it

Tags: reactjs

I am having an issue with setting the initial value of a radio group (from a value passed into the function) like this:

`export default function SportTeamRanking({team, ...props}) {`

So right now I have a Radio Group with 4 radio buttons and the value I want to pre-select or check is contained in the **team** object specified above (something like team.ranking). This value is passed from a class component into this function. So let's say the team object had a team.ranking value of "rank2" so ideally the Rank 2 radio button would be pre-selected when the function loads.

I have an initial state:

```
const [value, setValue] = React.useState("");
```

I've tried setting the `React.useState(team.ranking)` but still no button is selected.

I also tried using the useEffect and run it only once:

```
useEffect(() => {
    setValue(team.ranking)
  }, []);
```

but with no luck. I tried console logging early on and seems like the **team** object is still empty while all of this code is already executed?

The goal of this function is to pre-load any saved value that might have been set before (from the team object passed in), then update to a new ranking value if required and save.

For extra info here is the radio group code in the return body:

```
<FormControl component="fieldset">
  <FormLabel component="legend">Team Ranking</FormLabel>
  <RadioGroup aria-label="ranking" name="ranking1" value={value} onChange={handleChange}>
    <FormControlLabel value="rank1" control={<Radio />} label="Rank 1" />
    <FormControlLabel value="rank2" control={<Radio />} label="Rank 2" />
    <FormControlLabel value="rank3" control={<Radio />} label="Rank 3" />
    <FormControlLabel value="rank4" control={<Radio />} label="Rank 4" />
  </RadioGroup>
</FormControl>
```

And the onChange is simply:

```
const handleChange = (event) => {
    setValue(event.target.value);
  };
```

Any suggestions are appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you have mentioned that the value is passed from a class component to a function component, see if the below code answers your question.

```
function FormControlLabelPosition(props) {

  const onChange = (e) => props.onChange(e.target.value)

  return (
    <FormControl component="fieldset">
      <FormLabel component="legend">Team Ranking</FormLabel>
      <RadioGroup aria-label="ranking" name="ranking1" value={props.value} onChange={onChange}>
        <FormControlLabel value="rank1" control={<Radio />} label="Rank 1" />
        <FormControlLabel value="rank2" control={<Radio />} label="Rank 2" />
        <FormControlLabel value="rank3" control={<Radio />} label="Rank 3" />
        <FormControlLabel value="rank4" control={<Radio />} label="Rank 4" />
      </RadioGroup>
    </FormControl>
  );
}

export default class Parent extends React.Component {
  state = {
    value: "rank4"
  }

  handleChange = (val:string) => this.setState({value: val})

  render() {
    return (<FormControlLabelPosition value={this.state.value} onChange={this.handleChange}/>)
  }
}
```

Try it out here: https://codesandbox.io/s/material-demo-4ilxb

Comment: Thanks for that suggestion @Karthick Vinod! I also figured it out by checking if the team state is available and not empty/null in parent component then render that function which now seems to be working

ie from parent class:

`{teams && (<SportTeamRanking team={team} classes={classes} />`